# C++ - ifstream getting the address of bytes in buffer

Tags: c++

Lets say for instance that I save some data into a stringstream like this:

```
char byte = 'A';
stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&byte), sizeof(char));

int aInt = 252;
stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&aInt), sizeof(int));
```

and later save the stream to a file.

Is it possible to get the address of the buffer at some position, for instance:

```
char* byte = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&file.seekg(0));
int* theInt = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&file.seekg(1));
```

I don't want to make any copies, so I can't use the read function. So instead of copying the content I want to obtain the address of that location that seekg is pointing to inside the buffer and use built in types to point to the data inside the buffer.

I can solve this by inserting the content of the file into a stringstream and use the .str() function like this:

```
std::string buffer = stream.str();
char* byte = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buffer[0]); // first byte is a char
int* theInt = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&buffer[1]); //next 1-5 bytes will be an int
```

but I want to avoid the copying from the file stream to yet another stream.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No. What you're doing with `stream.str()` **is** the way to do it.

Comment: istream represents in some cases a document in the disk, you cannot get the address of something that is not in memory, for that you would need to load the whole file into a buffer

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz damn, thanks

Comment: @Mamma, actually. Now that I thought about it a bit more, to avoid "copying", I think what you want to use is the `stringstream::rdbuf` function. So use `std::stringbuf *pbuf = stream.rdbuf()` to get a pointer to the internal buffer.  See here for more info: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/rdbuf/